# Race condition in accessing a list of mutliple threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

```
private FruitResult GetFruitResult(Fruits fruits)
{
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    foreach (string fruit in fruits)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => CheckFruitQuality(fruit, someOtherThings, ref fruitResult));
        threads.Add(t);
    }

    threads.ForEach(x => x.Start());
    threads.ForEach(x => x.Join());

    return fruitResult;
}

private void CheckFruitQuality(string fruit, SomeOtherThings someOtherThings, ref FruitResult fruitResult)
{
    ......
    get size and color
    ......

    Result r = new Result();
    r.Size = size;
    r.Color = color;

    fruitResult.FruitReports.Add(r);
}
```

Since the Thread constructor only takes a delegate, I had to return fruitResult as a reference. Now, how to lock fruitResult, so there won't be a race condition?

Comment: wrap FruitResult with lock(){...} inside or maybe use BlockingCollection<T>, it's thread safe.

Comment: How do you wrap it? It's inside a function call. Cannot use BlockingCollection because I had to use ObservableCollection

Comment: I think you should make your observableCollection thread safe then. Becouse of that I see two main ways you can chose, first is to wrap ObservableCollection to make sure it's thread safe (you could create interface which will sounds like ThreadSafeObservableCollection and here implement your ObservableCollection inside this interface. Second is to create static object for your locker and use this lock inside lambda. In my opinion you should create or extend existing interface due to make implementation more generic and possibility of use SlimLocker reader / writers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible you should try to avoid sharing state between threads. Locking reduces performance and scalability. Creating threads manually is not a best practice either. Threads are very expensive to create and your CPU can only process a limited number of them at the same time. It's better to let the thread pool manage the threads for you. Using `ref` parameters makes code less readable than simply returning a value from a method.

All those 3 problems can be solved by using [tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of threads. Then you can easily get the results back without using `ref` parameters. If `CheckFruitQuality` is a compute intensive operation you can try something like this:

```
private async Task<FruitResult> GetFruitResult(IEnumerable<string> fruits)
{
    var fruitResult = new FruitResult();
    // start the tasks
    var tasks = fruits.Select(fruit => Task.Run(() => CheckFruitQuality(fruit, someOtherThings)));

    // wait for them to complete
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    //process results
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        fruitResult.FruitReports.Add(result);
    }

    return fruitResult;
}

private Result CheckFruitQuality(string fruit, SomeOtherThings someOtherThings)
{
    // get size and color

    return new Result()
    {
        Size = size,
        Color = color
    };
}
```

If `CheckFruitQuality` is an I/O operation then you probably don't even need parallelism, just use async I/O.

Tasks are executed on thread pool threads, so they are much more efficient than creating new threads manually.

Comment: Almost perfect! Compared to the original code, when you process the results and populate to the FruitReports, you only have result in hand every time when you loop it. What if there is a result that crashes? How do I know which fruit it is that causes the crash?